# cant send back image from flask server to react server

Tags: javascript, axios

So i sent an image from react to flask using an axios post request , the image is in form of a formdata

```js
const response = await axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload",
      headers: { "content-type": "multipart/form-data" },
      data: filou,
```

in the flask back , i recieve image , store it , then send as a responce another image

```py
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def fileUpload():
    print("hello")
    
    print(request.files)
    
    # check if the post request has the file part
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        print("no file")
        flash('No file part')
        return "redirect(request.url)"
    file = request.files['file']
    
    # If the user does not select a file, the browser submits an
    # empty file without a filename.
    if file.filename == '':
        print("no selected file")
        flash('No selected file')
        return redirect(request.url)
    
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        print("\n YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEYYYY \n")
        print(file.filename)
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        # print(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        new_filename = app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']
        print(new_filename)
        
        return send_file(f"output/final_output/panda.jpg")
```

when i recieve the image , i get it like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVWOd.png)

But i couldnt show it in react and i dunno how to do it (i tried many techniques , blob , createObjectURL ...etc)

```js
.then((response) => {
      const data = response.data;

      console.log("-----------------------------------------------------");
      console.log("I received");
      console.log(data);


      const img_bytes = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from(response.img, 'hex'));
      const blob = new Blob([img_bytes], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
      setoutImage(URL.createObjectURL(blob));


      // setoutImage(response.data)
      setDone(true);
    });
```

```js
{done == true && (
                  <img
                    src={outputUrl+outImage}
                    alt=""
                    width="400"
                  />
                )}
```

if someone can help .

Comment: Set `responseType: 'blob'` in the `axios` call, then use `URL.createObjectURL(response.data)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly what [Unmitigated](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9513184/unmitigated) said...

```js
axios
.get('your_url',{ responseType: 'blob' })
.then((response) => {
      const img = URL.createObjectURL(response.data);
      setoutImage(img);
      ...
    });
```